# Android appwidget throwing nullpointerexception

Tags: android, json, android-appwidget

i successfully created appwidget(stackview widget) and i parsed json and showed appwidget but i have nullpointexception.program working but when i close programm and click widget i have exception this is a my code

```
public class BriGeWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static final String TOAST_ACTION = "com.example.android.stackwidget.TOAST_ACTION";
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM = "com.example.android.stackwidget.EXTRA_ITEM";
private RemoteViews views;
private Intent intent;
public static int viewIndex;

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(TOAST_ACTION)) {

        viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);

        ItemI item = BriGeRemoteViewsFactory.itemList.get(viewIndex);
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, WidgetResult.class)
                .putExtra("KEY_title", item.getTitle())





                .addFlags(
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        intent = new Intent(context, BriGeRemoteViewsService.class);

        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.stackWidgetView, intent);

        views.setEmptyView(R.id.stackWidgetView, R.id.stackWidgetEmptyView);

        Intent templateIntent = new Intent(context,
                BriGeWidgetProvider.class);
        templateIntent.setAction(BriGeWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
        templateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetId);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent templatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, templateIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stackWidgetView,
                templatePendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}


public class BriGeRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

    return new BriGeRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}

static class BriGeRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    public static ArrayList<ItemI> itemList;
    private Context context;
    private int appWidgetId;

    public BriGeRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        itemList = getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        itemList = getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        itemList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        ItemI item = itemList.get(position);

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.item_view);

        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettitle, item.getTitle());

        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img, getImageBitmap(item.getImage()));

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(BriGeWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
        Intent fillIntent = new Intent();
        fillIntent.putExtras(extras);

        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widgettitle, fillIntent);

        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.img, fillIntent);

        return rv;
    }

    private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    private ArrayList<ItemI> getData() {
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(context);
        return jp.getDataAsList();
    }
}
```

}

i have exception widgetprovider.if anyone knows solution please help me thanks

Comment: At what line do you have the exception ?

Comment: in this line ... ItemI item = BriGeRemoteViewsFactory.itemList.get(viewIndex);

Comment: You do not show how you declare itemList, but it is probably null

Comment: no you did not understand me.first time program working ,but if i should furn off programm then i have this exception.meybe problem is my itemlist is static,but i do not know how i can change it